# Angular 12 layout content in head gets rendered into body from @ symbol

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, angular12

My application is migrated to Angular12 from Angular10 and we are using MVC application for angular bootstrapping.

My Sample Layout file is

```html
@using ProjectName.UI.Models

@model ModelName

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vatica Health</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular.Json file configurations are

```json
"targets": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "deployUrl": "dist/",`your text`
            "index": "Views/Shared/_LayoutTemplate.cshtml",
            "main": "src/main.ts",`your text`
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "primeng",
            ],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "well365:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "well365:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "well365:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "codeCoverage": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

When build the project in dev mode Layout html file is appropriately generated but on generating in prod mode all the head content moves within body.

Found out that problem is occurring due to @ symbol so if move the lines such as model import in between somewhere of head content then head tag ends there and body tag is started.

Not sure why this is happening.